# LoopBack 4: Adding type attribute to an element in a SOAP request

Tags: typescript, soap, loopbackjs, loopback4, strong-soap

I'm using LoopBack 4 to access a third party SOAP API and am having difficulty getting a specific SOAP call to work. The documentation doesn't appear to cover this scenario.

Relevant parts of WSDL:

```
<xs:element name="change_item">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="change" nillable="true" type="q1:item_change" xmlns:q1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/configuration_services"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
...
<xs:complexType name="auto_adjust_item">
    <xs:complexContent mixed="false">
        <xs:extension base="tns:item_change">
            <xs:sequence/>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="auto_adjust_item" nillable="true" type="tns:auto_adjust_item"/>
<xs:complexType name="item_change">
    <xs:sequence/>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="item_change" nillable="true" type="tns:item_change"/>
```

Here is the element from a working request sent from a Java demo application:

```
<change xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns2:auto_adjust_item"/>
```

For everything I tried, this is what LoopBack is sending to the SOAP API (which returns an error):

```
<ns1:change/>
```

I initially tried creating classes, `auto_adjust_item` extending `item_change`, both without any properties.

I then created them as models using `lb4 model item_change` and `lb4 model auto_adjust_item`, which became `ItemChange` and `AutoAdjustItem`. `AutoAdjustItem` was changed to extend `ItemChange` instead of `Model`. I messed with the `@model` annotation parameters and nothing helped.

An instance of `AutoAdjustItem` is passed through the service interface where the parameter is defined as `change: ItemChange`.

Does anyone know how I can add the `type="auto_adjust_item"` attribute to the element in the SOAP request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

Parameter definition:

```
change: {
    $attributes: {
        $xsiType: string
    }
}
```

Pass this as the parameter:

```
const change = {
    $attributes: {
        $xsiType: '{http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/configuration_services}auto_adjust_item'
    }
}
```

Even better, create it as a class:

```
export class autoAdjustItem {
    $attributes = {
        $xsiType: '{http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/configuration_services}auto_adjust_item'
    }
}

const change = new autoAdjustItem();
```

The element in the SOAP request, which the server accepted:

```
<ns1:change xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/configuration_services" xsi:type="ns2:auto_adjust_item"/>
```

This feels like a bad workaround with the hard coded namespace, but it works and I'll take it. I've spent enough time on this one feature, thanks to the severe lack of support.

I got the idea to try this by staring at [this documentation](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Strong-soap.html#overriding-the-attributes-key), which looks very different from how the [tutorial](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/soap-calculator-tutorial.html) had me do things.